# How to make the output of ScientificForm computable

Tags: list-manipulation, number-representation

I am trying to extract the mantissas of a list of numbers using the `ScientificForm` and then do some operation on them. However, it seems that the output does not act like a number and is not computable (this is also noted in the documentation). I was wondering if there is a workaround for this?

Here is an example:

```
list = ScientificForm[#, NumberFormat -> (#1 &)] & /@ {12.34,23.45,345.6}
```

Then `Total@list` returns `1.234 + 2.345 + 3.456` without computing the sum.

Comment: @Nasser Could you elaborate? How would you get the mantissas?

Comment: `MantissaExponent /@ {12.34, 23.45, 345.6}` ?

Comment: @Syed Thanks, I didn't know about this function. However, it seems that this gives a mantissa different than that in scientific notation (where it should lie between 1 and 10). Am I right?

Comment: I think that you have asked two questions and yes you are right. The `MantissaExponent` will give a mantissa between 0 and 1. For addition, this is not useful since all exponents need to be the same before you add the mantissas; which brings us back to square one.

Comment: @Syed yes it's a different question, but I only asked because it was proposed as a solution with a slightly different answer. Thanks for your help, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I meant is since you have the original list, why not do the operation on it?  Like this (see also comment by Syed above on MantissaExponent)

```
list1 = {12.34, 23.45, 345.6};
m = Last /@ MantissaExponent /@ list1 
list1/10^(m - 1)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Total[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Instead of doing

```
list = ScientificForm[#, NumberFormat -> (#1 &)] & /@ list1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And then trying to do Total on the above, which will not work since it has wrappers around them.

Comment: Thanks, this would do the job. It is just a bit cumbersome, especially since```ManitssaExponent``` works slightly differently than the common scientific notation.

Comment: @Nasser the `Total` you have calculated is not going to be correct unless all exponents are the same. Then you add the mantissas and multiply.

Comment: @Syed Seems this actually works even for numbers with different exponents.

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is to do computations and display the result using the `Form` wrapper of choice. Compare the following for instance.

```
blist = ScientificForm /@ {12.34, 23.45, 345.6}
Total[blist]
Total[blist[[All, 1]]]
```

---

so I would say extract the first part.

```
list = ScientificForm[#, NumberFormat -> (#1 &)][[1]] & /@ {12.34, 
   23.45, 345.6}
```

or

```
list = First@ScientificForm[#, NumberFormat -> (#1 &)] & /@ {12.34, 
   23.45, 345.6}
```

If you look at the `TreeForm` output for individual numbers, it is clear that you need the first part.

[image]

---

```
2 list
```

> {24.68, 46.9, 691.2}

Comment: This is returning the numbers in the original list themselves. As mentioned in the question, I want to extract the mantissa. Can this be modified to do that?

Comment: The Total [ blist [[All,1]] ] is still returning the sum of the original numbers, not just the mantissas.